# MOD_REWRITE rule not working ignoring variables

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, seo

I did this rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/stock/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+) product_list.php?model=$1&year=$5 [L]
```

But it only takes model variable and ignores year. what im i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 4 capture groups in your regex while you reference the fifth with `$5`.

Comment: I changed it to 4 still doesnt work. I was trying with 5 to see if it worked.

Comment: what is your testing url  before rewriting ?